# In next 13 with app directory routing , is it possible to receive a file through POST request and STREAM it to an external API?

Tags: javascript, next.js, form-data, node-streams

I am trying to upload a picture from browser and stream it from my backend to imgur's api, but it's only working with small pictures. When I try to upload a 80kb picture for example, it takes 1 minute and then crash, but it does work with a 28kb pic. So I am wondering if this is a memory issue and if it`s possible to use streams in this situation.

I have this route.js file which handles a form-data POST request:

```
import uploadImage from "@/utils/uploadImage";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import path from 'path'

export const POST = async (req) => {
    try {
        const formData = await req.formData();
        const file = formData.get('image');
        const allowedExtensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']
        if (!file || !allowedExtensions.includes(path.extname(file.name))){
            return NextResponse.json({
                ok:false,
                msg: 'Invalid file'
            })
        }
        let newFileURL = await uploadImage(file)
        if (!newFileURL){
            return NextResponse.json({
                ok:false,
                msg: 'Invalid file'
            })
        }
        
        return NextResponse.json({
            ok:true,
            url: newFileURL
        })
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return new Response(null, {
            status:500
        })
    }

}
```

Here is the code of **uploadImage** function:

```
export default async function uploadImage(fileBlob){
    const postData = new FormData()
    postData.set('image', fileBlob, fileBlob.name)
    let response = await fetch(process.env.IMGUR_UPLOAD_URL, {
        method:'POST',
        body:postData,
        headers:{
            "Authorization": "Client-ID " + process.env.IMGUR_CLIENT_ID
        }
    })
    response = await response.json()
    if (!response.status){
        return null
    }

    
    return response.data.link

}
```